# Did Darth Vader do the first one-armed lift in the movies?

Tags: cinema-history

In *Star Wars* Darth Vader lifts one of the rebel soldiers off the deck using one powerful arm.  This lift with slight variations has been used in subsequent movies and TV programs to demonstrate general badassery, e.g. *The Wrath of Khan*, the first three *Terminator* movies, *Man of Steel*, etc.

**Was Vader's lift the first time one man has lifted another in that fashion in the movies?**

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe so.

I was looking through **Neck Lift Tropes** and I came across a Live Action Film from **1929** titled, **The Kiss**. (I couldn't find a pick of the actual act, but I did find video leading up to the scene)

> In The Kiss, a homicidally angry Charles does this to Pierre after
>   catching Pierre kissing Charles's wife.
>   http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeckLift

Comment: In addition, Young Frankenstein predates Star Wars by three years and includes a one-armed lift as mentioned on the TV Tropes page. So definitively not.